# Save PHP-generated JSON to text file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, text

(This question is following on from my previous problem which has been fixed [(Here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200782/populating-a-search-input-box-using-php-with-values-from-a-mysql-table/10200967#10200967)

I found a similar question to this [(Here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402935/convert-html-output-into-a-plain-text-using-php) but the solution wasn't quite what I was looking for.

I currently have a JQuery styled autocomplete search engine on my site, called [(fcbkcomplete)](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html). The original operation of the script ran from a .txt file, looked up the manually-entered values and outputted them in the autocomplete results. However, I want the script to get the values from a MYSQL database instead of being manually entered into a .txt file as I eventually want the user to have the option of adding their own values.

I have therefore made the Javascript call a .php file instead of .txt with this script in it:

```
//connection details

$getData = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM tblIngredient"); 

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array($getData)) 
 {
     echo "{\"key: value:\";
     echo $info['Name'];
     echo "key: value:\"";
     echo $info['Name'];
     echo "}, ";
 }
```

This script works and outputs the data in the correct format:

```
{"key": "vodka","value": "vodka"}, {"key": "tequila","value": "tequila"},
```

**So I need to know how I then convert this JSON output into data.txt (so as the database table grows, the .txt file is updated automatically when the script is run)**

This is the final step in the search on my site so any help is much appreciated.

-Matt

Comment: Something with your title is wrong. HTML can't generate PHP.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to save to the txt file?

Comment: I think he meant the other way around, but I still believe something's wrong with the title, as he seems to be trying to convert JSON to Text file

Comment: Related: use [json_encode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: apologies I've edited the title I wrote it the wrong way round. Basically Im getting a html output from the above script data.php (pulling values from my table tblIngredient). Im wanting to know how I can use these values so they appear in the autocomplete results (It originally worked from a manually entered data.txt file).

@webbiedave - how exactly does the json encode script work?

Comment: You're not getting HTML output, but [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) output. I've edited the question title to reflect that. Also, you should be using PDO or MySQLI instead of `mysql*` functions as [they are deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really tell which bit of data you want to save to this txt file but I'm going to assume it's this:

```
{"key": "vodka","value": "vodka"}, {"key": "tequila","value": "tequila"},
```

If it isn't you can just substitute it for what you want.

I think the function you are looking for is `fopen()` specifically using 'a' as the second argument.

From the manual:

> **'a'** Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file.
>   If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Here's an example (a very brief one at that) of how to use it.

```
$string = '{"key": "vodka","value": "vodka"}, {"key": "tequila","value": "tequila"}';
$fp = fopen('somefile.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $string);
fclose($fp);
```

One thing to consider here (amongst others) is the file will need the proper permissions for write access.

Comment: This worked nicely and is now writing the data to a .txt file which is exactly what I wanted, however It's not appearing in the auto complete results. Im wondering if this is because my results are formatted like this: {"key": "vodka","value": "vodka"},{"key": "tequila","value": "tequila"},{ ..... This is missing spaces after each of the commas (bit of a silly question but what code do I use for a whitespace, &nbsp would be for html but I thought it was literally by hitting spacebar >.<)

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest I would have assumed just hitting the space bar would be ok. I don't think the lack of a space is breaking it though. It may the way it being brought back into the page.

Comment: You've been a great help with this, quick question, How would I get a "[" at the start and a "]" at the end of the generated .txt file?

$getData = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM tblIndredient"); 
$start = '[';
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array($getData)) 
 {
 $string = '{"key": "'.$info['Name'].'","value": "'.$info['Name'].'"}, ';
 $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
 fwrite($fp, $string);
 fclose($fp);
 }

....Im not sure how to do it so it appears just at the start and end without it appearing on every database entry.

Comment: Don't bother writing the [ ] to the file, fetch your file content into a string, then concatenate the string with [ ], `$string = 'yourcodefromthefile'; $string = '[' . $string .']';`

Comment: Im not extremely experienced with PHP, how exactly do I go about fetching the content of data.txt and re-write it with the brackets? As the $string variable is only defined within the while loop (Does the code you pasted go within the while loop?

Comment: `$string = '[' . file_get_contents('yourfile.txt') . ']';`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pointing the autocomplete to data.txt, why don't you just point it to your PHP page?

```
$("element").fcbkcomplete({
    ...
    json_url: "fetched.php",
    ...
});
```

Comment: Then your JSON is probably wrong and putting it into a txt file will likely not help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) & [ob_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) then put in a text file with [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
<?php
$getData = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM tblIngredient");
ob_start();
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($getData))
{
    echo "{\"key: value:\"";
    echo $info['Name'];
    echo "key: value:\"";
    echo $info['Name'];
    echo "}, ";
}
$return = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents('./data.txt',$return);
?>
```

Or if its valid json you actually want to save to file then you use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the array

```
<?php
$getData = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM tblIngredient");

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($getData)){
    $result[]=$info['Name'];
}
file_put_contents('./data.txt',json_encode($result));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood you basically want to write this output to a txt file, right?
In this case you shouldn't use echo function but fopen and fwrite. Take a look to this [TUTORIAL](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php)